# Is there a way to get the min values for all the summed groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the sum for the values for each of the groups.

```
   rf = condition1.groupby(by=['Well Name','Phase'])['Sum of Activity Time 
   (Hr)'].sum()


   Well Name              |   Phase    |       Value   |

   TIGER 55-2-12 LOV 8H   |    INT     |       56.25
                          |    MNH     |       58.25
                          |    SRF     |       34.25
   UNIVERSITY 20 PW 2502H |    INT     |       52.75
                          |    MNH     |       72.50
                          |    SRF     |       28.5
   UNIVERSITY 20 PW UNIT  |    INT     |       64.50
                          |    MNH     |       132.50
                          |    SRF     |       30.00
   UNIVERSITY 20 TG UNIT  |    INT     |       57.00
                          |    MNH     |       129.50
                          |    SRF     |       25.50
```

I need to have something like this: Just the min of each of the 3 phases as you can see each of those values are the min of the sum for each group. Any ideas?

```
    Well Name              |   Phase    |       Value   | 

    UNIVERSITY 20 PW 2502H |    INT     |       52.75
    TIGER 55-2-12 LOV 8H   |    MNH     |       58.25
    UNIVERSITY 20 TG UNIT  |    SRF     |       25.50
```

as you can see, just the minimums of ths sums of for the groups.

Comment: I think you can just take your result, `.groupby('Well Name')['Value'].min()` or something similar?

Comment: @alkasm I tried that and give the result of the min vale for each phase but not the min of the sum. So in this post rf has no columns apparently, so may need to do it using the index "phase" but not sure how to do that.

Comment: Well, I'd try something out but I have no copy/pastable example :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rf=pd.DataFrame(condition1.groupby(by=['Well Name','Phase'])['Sum of Activity Time 
   (Hr)'].sum())
rf=rf[rf.isin(rf.groupby('Well Name').min()['Sum of Activity Time (Hr)'].tolist())].dropna()
```

Also you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
rf=pd.DataFrame(condition1.groupby(by=['Well Name','Phase'])['Sum of Activity Time 
   (Hr)'].sum())
i=0
while i<len(rf.index):
    if rf.loc[rf.index.values[i]][0] != rf.loc[rf.index.values.tolist()[i][0]].apply(min)[0]:
        rf = rf.drop(rf.index.values.tolist()[i])
    else:
        print(i)
        i+=1
rf
```

Output:

```
Well Name              |   Phase    |       Value   | 

UNIVERSITY 20 PW 2502H |    INT     |       52.75
TIGER 55-2-12 LOV 8H   |    MNH     |       58.25
UNIVERSITY 20 TG UNIT  |    SRF     |       25.50
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i get this error                                                        :AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-12807ba5d1a8> in <module>
      1 i=0
      2 while i<len(rf.index[0]):
----> 3         if rf.loc[rf.index.values[i]].values != rf.loc[rf.index.values.tolist()[i][0]].apply(min).values:
      4             rf = rf.drop(rf.index.values.tolist()[i])
      5         else:

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: It's weird, it works on my computer. Try the other code that leaves you!

Comment: so, for the other one 'well name' cannot be group because in the first snapshot rf grouped well name and phase, so they are now part of the index. the "While" method made more sense but seems the ".value"  is not valid:  if rf.loc[rf.index.values[i]].values != rf.loc[rf.index.values.tolist()[i][0]].apply(min).values

Comment: have you done: `rf=pd.DataFrame(condition1.groupby(by=['Well Name','Phase'])['Sum of Activity Time 
   (Hr)'].sum())` first? I don't get any mistakes and if I can group

Comment: Do you get an error when you try `rf=rf[rf.isin(rf.groupby('Well Name').min()['Sum of Activity Time (Hr)'].tolist())].dropna()` after `rf=pd.DataFrame(condition1.groupby(by=['Well Name','Phase'])['Sum of Activity Time 
   (Hr)'].sum())`? what error do you get? it's in my computer work. Can be due to differents versions of python

Comment: you were right, i was missing a bracket. THANKS A LOT.